# Numerical sampling in hierarchical Bayesian models (HBM)

Tags: sampling, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, numerical-integration

I am reading chapter 5 of $\textit{Bayesian Data Analysis}$ by Gelman $\textit{et al.}$. There it explains the few steps of data analysis for hierarchical models and if I quote from the book it will be:

"We first perform the following three steps analytically.

1. Write the joint posterior density, $p( \theta, \phi|y)$, in unnormalized
   form as a product of the hyperprior distribution $p(\phi)$, the
   population distribution $p(\theta|\phi)$, and the likelihood $p(y|\theta)$.
2. Determine analytically the conditional posterior density of $\theta$ given
   the hyperparameters $\phi$; for fixed observed $y$, this is a function
   of $\phi$, $p(\theta|\phi, y)$.
3. Estimate $\phi$ using the Bayesian paradigm; that is, obtain its
   marginal posterior distribution, $p(\phi|y)$.

The first step is immediate, and the second step is easy for conjugate models
because, conditional on $t/J$, the population distribution for $\theta$ is just the iid
model (5.1), so that the conditional posterior density is a product of conjugate
posterior densities for the components $\theta_j$.
The third step can be performed by brute force by integrating the joint
posterior distribution over $\theta$:
$$p(\phi|y) = \int{p(\phi,\theta|y)d\theta} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(5.4)}"$$

Now my question is whether we can (in a numerical approach) sample from $p(\phi,\theta|y)$ and ignore the $\theta$s to generate a sample of $p(\phi|y)$?

Comment: In your last line, do you really mean "... the $\theta$s to generate a sample of $p(\phi|y)$" (switching the $\phi$ and $\theta$)?  It would go better with eq. 5.4 above...

Comment: Oops! Exactly...

Comment: @jbowman, so I assume it is correct?

Comment: That's correct.  You can sample from $p(\phi,\theta|y)$ and ignore the $\theta$ to get a sample from the marginal distribution $p(\phi|y)$.

Comment: (The question is not exact duplicate but is about the same issue, namely, that the irrelevant variables in samples from the joint distribution can simply be ignored).